# WCF and multiple clients

Tags: wpf, wcf, iis

I have a WCF hosted in IIS, at the same time I have two clients, a WPF application and a Window Phone Application. My program work in the way that, the Window Phone Application will send a Message to the WCF and then the WCF will send it to the WPF application. How can I achieve it?

I have take a look at callback, but I believe what it does is to return a message back to the Window Phone Application after the Phone Application consume the WCF service. But what I want my program to do is to send the Msg from the Phone App to the WPF application instead.

please guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it this way:

- inside the WPF application, host a second WCF service to receive that message - your WPF application becomes a WCF server
- when a message comes in from the Windows Phone into your WCF service in IIS, that service class then becomes a WCF client to the WPF app and send that message onwards to the other WCF service

Callback won't work - since callback can only call back to the original caller (your Windows Phone, here) and that's not what you want.

Comment: Would writting the value to a text file from the WCF and use the WPF to read it constantly to look out for changes be a okay idea?

Comment: @Sydnal: it might work - if the WCF service and the WPF app run on the same machine - but I would not do it this way. By doing it like this, the WPF app must poll regularly for any changes - creating a WCF service inside the WPF app would only be invoked / used when a message has really come in. Seems more efficient that way.